# Unable to return the value using recursion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve Persistent Bugger Kata. I have written the below code, but unable to properly return final value. Although it logs the correct value. 
I am trying to use recursion.

```
const persistence = num => {
  x = num.toString();
  x = x.split('');
  console.log(x);

  if (x.length === 1) {
    return parseInt(x.join());
    // console.log(`num is ${x}`);
    // return x;
  }
  if (x.length > 1) {
    len = x.length;
    arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (i === 0) {
        arr.push(x[i]);
      } else {
        arr.push(arr[0] * x[i]);
        arr.shift();
      }
      num = parseInt(arr.join());
    }
    persistence(num);
  }
};
```

I am trying to **return** the final value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return` before `persistence(num);`

```
const persistence = num => {
  x = num.toString();
  x = x.split('');
  console.log(x);

  if (x.length === 1) {
    return parseInt(x.join());
    // console.log(`num is ${x}`);
    // return x;
  }
  if (x.length > 1) {
    len = x.length;
    arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (i === 0) {
        arr.push(x[i]);
      } else {
        arr.push(arr[0] * x[i]);
        arr.shift();
      }
      num = parseInt(arr.join());
    }
    return persistence(num);
  }
};
```